# Plotting SVC decision region

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, svm

I am following some SVC code in a book using moon_dataset.

here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=0.15)

rbf_kernel_svm_clf = Pipeline([
        ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
        ("svm_clf", SVC(kernel="rbf", gamma=5, C=0.001))
        ])
rbf_kernel_svm_clf.fit(X, y)
```

am i have tried plotting any of these [graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DUDs.png) with the following code but nothing so far.

```
plt.scatter(X, y)
```

any help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *something more* than just a scatter plot to plot the decision regions. A very useful module for this is [MLxtend](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/), which makes it very easy to plot the decision regions of a fitted model with [`plot_decision_regions`](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/plotting/plot_decision_regions/). Here's how you could get it done using your example:

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plot_decision_regions(X, y, clf=rbf_kernel_svm_clf.named_steps['svm_clf'], legend=2)
```

[image]